# Simulate the effect of light over time

Tags: animation, texture-painting, lighting, ambient-occlusion

I would like to simulate the effect, that has light, over a periode of time on an object. For example on the begining of my animation my wooden object looks bright and new and on the end of the animation it is darker. For that I only changed the texture color during the animation. Now my problem is, that my Model ist quite complex and ther are parts, that are kompleatly hidden and shhould not be efekted. I would like Blender to automaticly detect, whitch parts of my object are being more exposed to the light and just darken that. Is it possible? I thought of maybe somehow using the ambiente oclussion?

It will be a Film. It does not have to be in the material, but I just do not know how to do it. I have this image, where the edges are dark, becouse of an another object, that was covering it and only the edges were exposed to light. now in the beginig of the animation the whole face shold by the same color and during the animation the edges should get darker

[image]

Thanks

Comment: are  you using eevee or cycles?

Comment: I am using cycles

Comment: Animate the intensity of the light.

Comment: How does the animation of the intensity of the light influence only certen faces?

Comment: What is your intended output? Are you making an animation for a movie file or just to frames? Could you just animate your scene lighting and render the result as your movie then? Why does this need to be in the material/texture?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply bake the light/shadows and then use them as a mask.

1. Bake a Combined Pass (default settings work fine)
2. Use the resulting BW texture as a mask for a *MixRGB node*
3. Done

<sub>Have some tan Suzanne...</sub>

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It will be a Film. It does not have to be in the material, but I just do not know how to do it. I have this image, where the edges are dark, becouse of an another object, that was covering it and only the edges were exposed to light. now in the beginig of the animation the whole face shold by the same color and during the animation the edges should get darker

[image]